# Pokemon Go compatibility with Moto E 2nd gen

Tags: pokemon-go

My phone is a 6.0.1 Android..it follows all the criteria for compatibility with Pokémon Go.  I was playing fine until the mandatory update and now it tells me my phone is not compatible

Comment: Cool story. What's the question?

Comment: the question is why is not compatible and what should I do to sign in

Comment: it's not compatible because your phone isn't good enough to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Moto E 2nd Gen is not fully compatible with Pokemon Go, so it won't appear in your search in Play Store. Personally, i think it is probably caused by the fact Moto E2 doesn't have a gyroscope, so it's augmented reality capabilities are very poor if not non existent. The way i found to play the game was downloading the APK file of the game somewhere on the web. The downside is the problem you're facing now, you can't update the game from the Play Store (since it's said to be "unsupported by your phone"), so you have to keep downloading newer APK files of the game to keep it running on your phone. I hope i helped in any way.